# Why are we taking the sum of the cost/error function output array? What's its significance?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I know cost function helps in error calculation but what's the significance of taking the sum of the errors instead of just considering the error array which we obtained as an output
X is a 100x4 array and y is a 100x1 array and theta a 4x1 array are the weights and I am trying to predict the value of y.
Cost function calculates the sigmoid value of the dot product of X and theta and then calculates the difference between our predicted value with original y array and then sums the array.

```
 costFunction(X, y, theta): 
    hThetaX = sigmoid(dotProduct(X, theta)) #hThetaX is predicted output
    return np.sum(np.abs(y - hThetaX))
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Much more information is needed about where did you get this  "cost function", what is it used for, preferably define it using math notation rather than Python code.

Comment: Thanks Juho. I have edited my question to provide as much details as possible. :)

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but how would you "just consider the error array which we obtained as an output"? For instance, is an error array e1 = [1, -0.2, 3, 5] indicative of a lower error than that of an error array e2 = [0, 9, -2.3, 7] ? If I do the squared sum of errors, I can see immediately that e2 shows a higher error, since the cost function is higher.

Comment: @CodeVib What kind of data do you have? Are you trying to fit a model (estimate parameters? the thetas?)? You should be able to explain the model and what method you are using (as this function most likely is part of something). I suppose you did not write this code but found it from somewhere, in which case you should be able to at least give a reference. Knowing what you are trying to do would also help explaining whether/why summing is useful for that purpose.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala The data is stock market data, and I am learning to build the neural networks using Genetic algorithms for my weight(theta) prediction. Genetic algorithm helps to get the best possible weight(theta) and then I use that value of theta and X to calculate my cost function. Actually, Cristina answered my question. I was looking for intuitive reason why there was summing of the error array.

Comment: @Cristina This explains very clearly. I got the idea now. Thanks a ton
Perhaps you could add that comment in your answer. It helped

Comment: @CodeVib Great, glad to hear it clarified the concept for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cost function gives you a metric for how "good" your predictor is: the lower the cost, the better your predictor.
So your target while training a predictor is to minimise the cost function (ideally, you would want it to be zero).

This is what machine learning algorithms do: optimise the parameters of the predictor in order to minimise the cost function. If you didn't have a handy cost function like the (squared) sum of errors, you would not know how well your predictor is doing.

To give a simple example: assuming you are training a predictor $P$, first with the vector of coefficients $\omega_1$ and then with $\omega_2$, getting as result the following error vectors:

$e_1 = [1, -0.2, 3, 5]$

$e_2 = [0, 9, -2.3, 7]$

Just by looking at the error vectors, how would you decide whether parameters $\omega_1$ or $\omega_2$ are better?

In contrast, if you calculate a cost function on each vector (for instance, the squared sum of errors), you obtain

$cost_1 = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{4} e_{1i}^2 = 35.04$

$cost_2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{4} e_{2i}^2 = 135.29$

Like this, it is immediately obvious that the error vector $e_2$ is indicative of a higher error, since the cost function is higher. So you would know that using the coefficients $\omega_1$ for $P$ is the better choice.